# Don't ask before terminating mobile data connection

Tags: samsung, stock-android

My Samsung mobile phone (Android 4.x, released this year) keeps asking me every time if I **really** want to terminate my mobile data connection. No checkbox to remember the setting. That's annoying: More often than not I forget to confirm, and I'm on a data plan that charges per ping.

**EDIT**: The switch I'm using opens up when I swipe down from the very top of the display. I've seen this layout on my phone and on two other Samsung tablets, so I assume it's pretty standard.

Is there any setting to stop these messages once and forever? My question is kind of the opposite of https://android.stackexchange.com/q/67517/13266 .

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there's any *setting* for that (Samsung has certainly more than one device, and I don't know them all with all their specifics). But there are other means/approaches to this:

- you might try some of the [toggle switches](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists.php?topic=cat;id=181) and widgets available on *Google Play*
- you could check for some automation tool like [tasker](/questions/tagged/tasker), which have the feature of toggling mobile data. At least *Tasker* permits to create widgets on the homescreen bound to specific tasks, so you could create a toggle-widget yourself

Both approaches should work independent of the device you're going to use them on.

Comment: Thanks. I'd rather avoid installing an app just for that. I've described the switch I'm using in my edit above, does that ring a bell?

Comment: That's pretty much standard (at least since Android 4.x), yes. But on none of my devices I was ever asked for a confirmation there. Admitted, I'm not using any Samsung phone…